# Trigger change when using val(...) on a select tag

Tags: jquery, events, select

how is it possible to trigger change on a select tag without wrapping .val() or doing something like this

```
$('#id').val('...').trigger('change');
```

Maybe there is a event like the following that could make the job

```
    $(element).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
        // Do something
    });
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the value in javascript does not fire any event.  You will need to do as you have posted and call `trigger` or `change()`.

The only other solution I can think of is some sort of hacky solution of using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to check if the value has changed on some regular interval.  But this just seems like an awful idea.